# What is happening with vector<string> array?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am writing a lex scanner in which I define an array as follows:

```
// array of vector<string>
std::vector<std::string> Lexicals[5] = {
    //  [0] OPERATORS (pre-initialized with values)
    {"...", "..."},
    //  [1] PUNCTUATIVES (pre-initialized with values)
    {"...", "..."},
    //  [2] KEYWORDS (pre-initialized with values)
    {"...", "..."},
    //  [3] IDENTIFIERS  - add as found
    std::vector<std::string>(),
    //  [4] LITERALS  - add as found
    std::vector<std::string>()
};
```

With the following `enum`, I can evaluate the `lexType` and get the matching `vector` by the `enum` value (0 - 4):

```
enum LexType {
    OPERATOR, 
    PUNCTUATION, 
    KEYWORD, 
    IDENTIFIER, 
    LITERAL
};
```

It is the `IDENTIFIER` and `LITERAL` options that are causing problems. The following logic attempts to retrieve the correct vector container and either add a new value and identify the position or identify the position of an existing value:

```
case LexType::IDENTIFIER:
case LexType::LITERAL: {
    string val(read_buffer(), m_length);
    //  Lexicals[3] || [4]
    vector<string> lex = Lexicals[m_lexType];
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    //  make sure value is not already in the vector
    if(!lex.empty()){
        it = find(lex.begin(), lex.end(), val);
        if(it == lex.end()) {                    
            lex.push_back(val);
            it = std::find(lex.begin(), lex.end(), val);
        }
    } else {                
        lex.push_back(val);
        it = find(lex.begin(), lex.end(), val);
    }

    m_lexical = it - lex.begin();
}
break;
```

At each iteration following the first pass, `!lex.empty()` is bypassed. I am just trying to figure out what is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely this line:

```
vector<string> lex = Lexicals[m_lexType];
```

Here you get the vector *by value*, which means it's *copied*. Then when you later do `lex.push_back(val)` you're only appending to the *copy* and not the original vector.

Instead have `lex` be a *reference* to the actual (original) vector:

```
vector<string>& lex = Lexicals[m_lexType];
```

Comment: Although I'm getting an error now: `D:\RzPlus/token.cpp:16: multiple definition of `Lexicals'`. Lexicals is declared in an included header. I'm making the big jump from C# and Python into C++ so I'm learning big lessons.

Comment: @IAbstract There's a difference between *declarations* and *definitions*. In the header file you should *declare* the array (e.g. `extern std::vector<std::string> Lexicals[5];`), then in a single sourcel file (a.k.a. [*translation unit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)) you *define* the array like you do in the code you show.

Comment: It seems that I also had to put the declarations within a namespace :/ ...it works now, thanks!!!